# How do I get specific value from all keys in an object and store it in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm already struggling for quite some time to extract all the labels from the object in the picture below and then store them in a single array using JavaScript...

[image]

i have been trying something like this:

```
for (let i = 0, len = nav_items.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(nav_items[i].label);
}
```

But this only prints three different values... I need all the labels in one array together.

The ideal outcome would be an array of:

```
["Getting started", "Components", "For designers"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your array in to an array with only the label values like this:

```
var onlyLabelsArr = nav_items.map(item => item.label);
console.log(onlyLabelsArr);
```

will give you:

```
["Getting started", "Components", "For designers"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will rate this a solution once the 10min timer will allow it!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array and push those values in it

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0, len = nav_items.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(nav_items[i].label);
}

console.log(arr)
```

output

```js
["Getting started", "Components", "For designers"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result using `for...of` loop also. Result using `Array.prototype.map` and `for...of` looop.

```js
const arr = [
  { label: "Getting started" },
  { label: "Components" },
  { label: "For designers" },
];

// Using Array.prototype.map
const result1 = arr.map(({ label }) => label);
console.log(result1);

// Using for...of loop
const result2 = [];
for (let obj of arr) {
  const { label } = obj;
  result2.push(label);
}
console.log(result2);
```